# How to tell if a GitHub release was made securely

Tags: github, github-api, qooxdoo

Is it possible to tell if a release which is published on a GitHub repo was made by someone who logged in with 2FA?

The reason for asking is that we have a tool that integrates GitHub releases (from repos made by other people, ie not part of our GitHub organisation) into an application, and is capable of auto-updating to the latest release.

Although it's user friendly to auto-update, if someone were to steal the credentials of that GitHub user (because they do not use 2FA) then the auto-update could end up installing maliciously crafted code.  This scenario has happened to npmjs.

It would be useful to be able to identify that the release was made by someone who does not use 2FA and warn that the release might be "unsafe".

Our application is part of Qooxdoo http://www.qooxdoo.org, which is an open source Javascript development framework.